# XSL add a wrapper every time sum equals 12

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to turn this

```
<root>
  <item columns="4"></item>
  <item columns="8"></item>
  <item columns="12"></item>
  <item columns="4"></item>
  <item columns="4"></item>
  <item columns="4"></item>
  <item columns="2"></item>
  <item columns="10"></item>
</root>
```

into this

```
<root>
  <row>
    <item columns="4"></item>
    <item columns="8"></item>
  </row>
  <row>
    <item columns="12"></item>
  </row>
  <row>
    <item columns="4"></item>
    <item columns="4"></item>
    <item columns="4"></item>
  </row>
  <row>
    <item columns="2"></item>
    <item columns="10"></item>
  </row>
</root>
```

Comment: Hi Kirk, you seem to be an avid SO user. Surely, you know and may have even commented once before that SO is not a code scripting service. Please make an earnest effort and return for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="aggregate">
            <xsl:with-param name="items" select="item"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="aggregate">
    <xsl:param name="items" select="/.."/>
    <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="stack-items" select="$items[position() &lt;= $i]" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="sum($stack-items/@columns) >= 12 or $i >= count($items)">
            <row>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$stack-items"/>
            </row>
            <xsl:if test="$i &lt; count($items)">
                <xsl:call-template name="aggregate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$items[position() > $i]"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="aggregate">
                <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$items"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Do a search for *sibling recursion* for an alternative method.

Comment: Very nice logic sir.

Comment: Can’t figure out my specific implementation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37163878/need-to-implement-an-xsl-solution-but-having-an-issue

Answer (score 1):

Here's an XSLT 2.0 solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!--
      Group <item> elements, ending each group when the sum of the @columns
      attribute of the current <item> element and the <item> elements that
      precede it is divisible by 12.
      -->
      <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-ending-with="
        *[sum((
            number(@columns),
            for $c in preceding-sibling::item/@columns return number($c)
          )) mod 12 eq 0]
      ">
        <row>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </row>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Nice grouping logic, if greater to 12 should be in single grouping. where as Michael Sir's answer will meet this possibility also. plus one.

Comment: What is the correct result when all items have 5 columns each? Your method groups them all together in a single row, having 40 columns in total. I believe there should be 3 rows of 15, 15 and 10 columns respectively.

Comment: Can’t figure out my specific implementation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37163878/need-to-implement-an-xsl-solution-but-having-an-issue

Answer (score 1):

Here a slightly shorter XSLT 1.0 version using `following-sibling` and an empty notest as default stack value ( `<xsl:param name="items" select="/@empty-node-set" />` ).
But basically same as michael.hor257k solution.

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="item[1]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:param name="items" select="/@empty-node-set" />
    <xsl:variable name="stack" select="$items | ." />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="sum($stack/@columns) >= 12 or not(following-sibling::item)"  >
            <row>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$stack"/>
            </row>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::item[1]" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::item[1]">
                <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$stack"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Using `/@empty-node-set` as empty stack was from [Best practice regarding empty node-set initialization](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/xsl-editors/2000JulSep/0068.html):

> ... the expression "/@empty-node-set" which is guaranteed 
>   (for XML 1.0) to be empty because the root node can never have attribute nodes.

Comment: What do you think the expression`/..` does? BTW, this one is mentioned not only in the same thread you quote, but also in the XSLT 1.0 specification itself: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#variable-values

Comment: Ok you are right I did not not think about what `/..` did in your solution, and also did not look to w3.org. :(

Comment: Nice logic(@empty-node-set).

Comment: Can’t figure out my specific implementation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37163878/need-to-implement-an-xsl-solution-but-having-an-issue