# Need to implement an XSL solution, but having an issue

Tags: xml, xslt

Can’t get my actual use-case to work. My code is currently

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template name="bundle-main">
    <div
      class="container"
      data-page-type="bundle"
      >
      <div class="row">
        <xsl:for-each select="//bundles-entry-by-bundle/entry/components/item">
          <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id" />
          <xsl:if test="@section-handle = 'components-text'">
            <xsl:for-each select="//*[concat(@section-handle,'-entry-by-bundle')]/entry[@id = $id]">
              <xsl:call-template name="components-text"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="@section-handle = 'components-link'">
            <xsl:for-each select="//*[concat(@section-handle,'-entry-by-bundle')]/entry[@id = $id]">
              <xsl:call-template name="components-link"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </div>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which prints one row, but it needs to implement the 12 column wrapper. My attempt isn’t worth posting as it didn’t quite work. I believe the key selector would be something like

```
sum(*[name() = concat($stack-items/@section-handle, '-entry-by-bundle')]/entry[@id = //bundles-entry-by-bundle/entry/components/item/@id]/columns/item/@handle) >= 12 or $i >= count($items)
```

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
  <bundles-entry-by-bundle>
    <section id="1" handle="bundles">Bundles</section>
    <entry id="3">
      <components>
        <item id="10" handle="perfect-fit-finder-4-columns" section-handle="components-link" section-name="Components: Link">Perfect fit finder (4 columns)</item>
        <item id="13" handle="collection-morning-run-8-column" section-handle="components-link" section-name="Components: Link">Collection: Morning run (8 column)</item>
        <item id="14" handle="collection-weekend-adventures-4-column" section-handle="components-link" section-name="Components: Link">Collection: Weekend Adventures (4 column)</item>
      </components>
    </entry>
  </bundles-entry-by-bundle>
  <fl-languages>
    <current-language handle="en" language="en" region="">English</current-language>
    <supported-languages>
      <item handle="en" main="yes">English</item>
      <item handle="fr">Français</item>
      <item handle="es">Español</item>
    </supported-languages>
  </fl-languages>
  <components-text-entry-by-bundle>
    <section id="4" handle="components-text">Components: Text</section>
    <error>No records found.</error>
  </components-text-entry-by-bundle>
  <components-link-entry-by-bundle>
    <section id="6" handle="components-link">Components: Link</section>
    <entry id="14">
      <headline-above mode="formatted" handle="collection-2" word-count="1" lang="en" handle-en="collection-2" handle-fr="" handle-es="">Collection</headline-above>
      <headline mode="formatted" handle="weekend-adventures" word-count="2" lang="en" handle-en="weekend-adventures" handle-fr="" handle-es="">Weekend Adventures</headline>
      <color has-color="no" />
      <columns>
        <item handle="4">4</item>
      </columns>
      <square-image size="23.28 MB" bytes="24413135" path="/uploads/components-link" type="image/jpeg">
        <filename>weekend-collection-en-1462960850.jpg</filename>
        <meta creation="2016-05-11T02:00:51-08:00" width="4656" height="4656" />
      </square-image>
      <click-hint>No</click-hint>
      <style>
        <item handle="modern">Modern</item>
      </style>
    </entry>
    <entry id="13">
      <headline-above mode="formatted" handle="collection" word-count="1" lang="en" handle-en="collection" handle-fr="" handle-es="">Collection</headline-above>
      <headline mode="formatted" handle="morning-run" word-count="2" lang="en" handle-en="morning-run" handle-fr="" handle-es="">Morning Run</headline>
      <color has-color="no" />
      <columns>
        <item handle="8">8</item>
      </columns>
      <square-image size="257 KB" bytes="263474" path="/uploads/components-link" type="image/jpeg">
        <filename>morning-run-square-en-1462939487.jpg</filename>
        <meta creation="2016-05-10T20:04:47-08:00" width="995" height="995" />
      </square-image>
      <wide-image size="457 KB" bytes="468427" path="/uploads/components-link" type="image/jpeg">
        <filename>morning-run-en-1462939487.jpg</filename>
        <meta creation="2016-05-10T20:04:47-08:00" width="2096" height="995" />
      </wide-image>
      <click-hint>No</click-hint>
      <style>
        <item handle="modern">Modern</item>
      </style>
    </entry>
    <entry id="10">
      <headline mode="formatted" handle="perfect-fit-finder" word-count="3" lang="en" handle-en="perfect-fit-finder" handle-fr="" handle-es="">Perfect fit finder</headline>
      <color r="0" g="168" b="225" has-color="yes">#00a8e1</color>
      <columns>
        <item handle="4">4</item>
      </columns>
      <icon size="2 KB" bytes="2102" path="/uploads/components-link" type="image/svg+xml">
        <filename>shoe-icon-en-1462909181.svg</filename>
        <meta creation="2016-05-10T11:39:41-08:00" width="100" height="41.7" />
      </icon>
      <click-hint>Yes</click-hint>
      <style>
        <item handle="bold">Bold</item>
      </style>
    </entry>
  </components-link-entry-by-bundle>
</data>
```

Here is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37125243/537998) I want to implement with the above XML and replacing my XSL.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="aggregate">
            <xsl:with-param name="items" select="item"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="aggregate">
    <xsl:param name="items" select="/.."/>
    <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="stack-items" select="$items[position() &lt;= $i]" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="sum($stack-items/@columns) >= 12 or $i >= count($items)">
            <row>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$stack-items"/>
            </row>
            <xsl:if test="$i &lt; count($items)">
                <xsl:call-template name="aggregate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$items[position() > $i]"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="aggregate">
                <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$items"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. Please (1) post the expected result and (2) explain the logic that needs to be applied in order to get it. Removing the parts that don't play a role in this would also be helpful. --- You say that your current XSLT "prints one row", but that's just not true. In fact, it does nothing because your top template is never called, and the built-in default templates step in to output all the text nodes in the source XML

Comment: You are totally right, my bad on not making my objective clearer. I’ve updated it to be clearer.

Comment: You are much more likely to get an answer if you post your expected output, as @michael.hor257k suggested.

Answer (score 3):

This code is obviously wrong:

```
//*[concat(@section-handle,'-entry-by-bundle')]
```

because when you use a string in a predicate, the effective value is true if the string is non-empty, and that is always the case here.

I suspect you are trying to select elements whose name is equal to the concatenation of (@section-handle,'-entry-by-bundle'). This seems to be a case where you should be using template rules rather than named templates. ("Silly xsl" has the perfect mechanism for your requirement, and you are ignoring it!). Replace this code:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="//bundles-entry-by-bundle/entry/components/item">
          <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id" />
          <!-- silly xsl will not let us programatically call templates -->
          <xsl:if test="@section-handle = 'components-text'">
            <xsl:for-each select="//*[concat(@section-handle,'-entry-by-bundle')]/entry[@id = $id]">
              <xsl:call-template name="components-text"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="@section-handle = 'components-link'">
            <xsl:for-each select="//*[concat(@section-handle,'-entry-by-bundle')]/entry[@id = $id]">
              <xsl:call-template name="components-link"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

by

```
<xsl:for-each select="//bundles-entry-by-bundle/entry/components/item">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[name()=concat(current()/@section-handle, '-entry-by-bundle'/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="component-text-entry-by-bundle">
  <!-- your component-text template -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="component-link-entry-by-bundle">
  <!-- your component-link template -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Haha, oh Michael that was a fun read -- Attempting implementation now! :D Thank you ! I’m still wrapping my mind around XSL thought patterns

Comment: if you have a moment to look over the updated problem, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I don't go along with this business of changing the question after it has been answered. It's a very long question and you haven't given any clues as to what has changed.