# XSL Grouping on totals based on previous node combinations

Tags: xslt, math, xpath

I have a list of nodes which have financial record information that I need to sort into groups of a particular size. I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do this though....

If I have a list of records such as:

```
<Records>
 <Record Count="5"/>
 <Record Count="5"/>
 <Record Count="5"/>
 <Record Count="4"/>
 <Record Count="4"/>
 <Record Count="4"/>
 <Record Count="3"/>
 <Record Count="3"/>
 <Record Count="2"/>
 <Record Count="1"/>
 <Record Count="1"/>
 <Record Count="1"/>
 <Record Count="1"/>
</Records>
```

I want to put them into groups of 5 (or as close to 5 as I can get)

I've tried something along the lines of

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Records/Record" group-by="ceiling((@Count + sum(preceding-sibling::Record/@Count)) div 5)">
```

Which works fine until the total needed is exact number is encountered.

```
<Record Count="4"/> The total thusfar is 27, the ceiling "group" being 6
<Record Count="3"/> The total here is 30, placing the ceiling "group" at also 6
```

This however breaks the rule that a "group" cannot exceed a total @Count of 5.

How could I go about sorting these into a list that best combines into groups of 5?

The expected result would be 
Groups of:
5, 5, 5, 4+1, 4+1, 4+1, 3+2, 3+1

Thanks!

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37124822/xsl-add-a-wrapper-every-time-sum-equals-12

Comment: Thanks, I had read this article - perhaps I missed something
It seems that the logic here looks for the point that our group reaches or bypasses the target number. I unfortunately need to be equal to or under the target number. With as few smaller groups as possible

Comment: What is the expected result, given your sample input?

Comment: If you want the minimum number of groups, this is basically a variation of the Knapsack Problem, and finding a solution is NP-hard (which basically means that you have to try every possible combination for finding an optimal solution). I don't know if this is possible using XSLT.